# SelectionHandler in Tabpanel

Tags: gwt, handler, tabpanel

I have two tabs on my screen.when I am changing the tabs.it does not get refreshed. I am trying to add SelectionHandler, but its giving error.
Can somebody help.

```
private TabPanel createTabPanel(){
        TabPanel tabPanel =new TabPanel();
        tabPanel.setWidth(450);
        tabPanel.setAutoHeight(true);

        TabItem tab1 = new TabItem("Cash Flow Rates");
        tab1.addStyleName("pad-text");
        TabItem tab2 = new TabItem("Holdings Rates");
        tab2.addStyleName("pad-text");
        payRateToolbar = createToolbar();
        tab1.add(payRateToolbar);
        tabPanel.add(tab1);
        tab2.add(payRateToolbar);
        tabPanel.add(tab2);
        tabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() 
                {
                    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) 
                    {
                        int tabId = event.getSelectedItem();
                        com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget tabWidget = tabPanel.getWidget(tabId);
                        if (tabWidget != null) 
                        {
                            //assumming that code to refresh will go here...
                        }
                    }
                });


        return tabPanel;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the TabPanel does not support `tabPanel.add(yourwidget)`, because no Tabtext is specified.
Use `tabPanel .add(payRateToolbar,  "Cash Flow Rates"))` instead.
you could also use a widget for displaying your TabText instead of just a string:

```
Label tab1 = new Label("Cash Flow Rates");
tab1.addStyleName("pad-text");
tabPanel .add(payRateToolbar,  tab1);
```